# How to do so if parameters are passed, then use them, if not, then standard input.txt, output.txt in java

Tags: java, command-line-interface

How to make sure that the name of the input file (input .txt)is not written in the program
but it could be changed using these type arguments (-Dinputfile)

I tried to figure it out myself, but nothing worked, I hope for your help...

Comment: The option `-Dinputfile=input.txt`, when placed before the class name, is a _System Property_ and you should get it using `String inputfile = System.getProperty("inputfile");`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.